# Capturing / calculating real time TCP delay / RTT using iperf or similar tools

Tags: delay, iperf

I want to ask, how to capture or check TCP delay / RTT every time using iperf? because I only see UDP delay jitter capture in iperf. If iperf can't capture that, is there any tools to capture real time TCP delay/RTT?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are running linux try the

```
$>ss -it
```

command.

This will provide you with the statistics of all ongoing TCP sessions.